# How to change titles/contents for TabSpec in TabHost?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing application which uses following code for making TabHost:

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec=mTabHostCategories.newTabSpec("Main");    
spec.setIndicator("Main");
spec.setContent(R.id.listViewMain);
mTabHostCategories.addTab(spec);

mTabSpecFirst=mTabHostCategories.newTabSpec("First");
mTabSpecFirst.setContent(R.id.listViewFirst); 
mTabSpecFirst.setIndicator(mCategoryFirst);
mTabHostCategories.addTab(mTabSpecFirst);

mTabSpecSecond=mTabHostCategories.newTabSpec("Second");
mTabSpecSecond.setContent(R.id.listViewSecond);
mTabSpecSecond.setIndicator(mCategorySecond);
mTabHostCategories.addTab(mTabSpecSecond);    

mTabHostCategories.setCurrentTab(0);
```

But then I need to change titles (indicators) and content for TabSpecs. How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change title in your `mCategoryFirst`
or simple pass a new TextView with your desired title to your TabSpec objects

Comment: mCategoryFirst is simple String object. How can I change it?

Comment: then simply call `mTabSpecFirst.SetIndicator("new title");` to change title for your first tab

Answer (score 0):

```
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TodaysTakeDemoActivity.class);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("todaystake").setIndicator("Todays Take",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icontodaystake)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WhatsCasting.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("whatscasting").setIndicator(
            "What's Casting", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.iconwhatscasting))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Contacts.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.iconcontact)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TopListActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("actortools").setIndicator("Actor Tools",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icontop10)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```